# Compulation errors in firestore.rules regex

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, re2

I'm trying to match any string that is a hashtag of any letters.

I've tested `^#{1}\p{L}+$` on multiple re2 testing sites and they all work fine, but in firestore.rules I get a compilation error:

```
Error: Compilation errors in firestore.rules:
[E] 33:33 - Unexpected 'p'.
[E] 33:37 - Unexpected '+'.
[E] 36:1 - Unexpected '}'.
```

Removing `\p{L}` gets rid of the error but as far as I can see, that should be valid.

My testing string (the first 3 should match, the rest should not)

```
#somethingcool
#かんぱい
#señor

#dbudn-asdasd
##burn
kurm
#durm burn
```

Edit:
Here's the rules in place

```
match /tags/{tagId} {
  allow create: if userIs(userId) && isValidTag(tagId)
  allow read: if userIs(userId)
}


function isValidTag(tag) {
  return tag.matches('^#{1}\p{L}+$') == true
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the actual rules you're using that don't work the way you expect.

Comment: There just changed that

Comment: @DougStevenson would love to hear back from you! Always value your input :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try escaping the backslash with another backslash:

```
return tag.matches('^#{1}\\p{L}+$') == true
```